# Create a Table from a Passed In Parameter in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

So, I am working on having a "schedule" table. I need a new table for every schedule that this program is creating in a collegiate environment. So, I would need one for SPRING2015, FALL2015, etc. That's what I want the tables names to be for example. We have a schedule being input into a base SCHEDULE table. The stored procedure would have to table in say 'FALL2015' and make the table called 'FALL2015'. I haven't found a good way to do this. I can only seem to make a temporary table or a table with a static name. We would need everything copied from the SCHEDULE table to the 'FALL2015' table that was made within the same procedure. That isn't the problem. I just need to find away around passing in a variable into the procedure that is the table name. I cannot seem to find a good way.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateScheduleTable 
    @TableName VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

CREATE TABLE @TableName (
    ClassID INT,
    SectionNum VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    StartTime INT,
    EndTime INT,
    Mon BIT,
    Tues BIT,
    Wed BIT,
    Thurs BIT,
    Fri BIT,
    Sat BIT,
    Sun BIT,
    TeacherID VARCHAR(6),
    RoomID INT,
    CONSTRAINT pk_Class PRIMARY KEY (ClassID, SectionNum)
)

    INSERT INTO @TableName
    (ClassID, SectionNum, StartTime, EndTime, Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun, TeacherID)
    SELECT ClassID, SectionNum, StartTime, EndTime, Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun, TeacherID
    FROM SCHEDULE


END
GO
-- End Procedure CreateScheduleTable --

EXEC CreateScheduleTable 'Hi'

SELECT * FROM #TempSchedule
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create so many tables?  Just have one table with a column for year and a column for season.  Then you have one table to manage and report from.  If you **must** do it your way then use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know the reason why you would create so many tables with the same schema, I would usually add one column into a table to Mark records for `SPRING2015, FALL2015,.... etc` ....

Anyway you would do it by using dynamic sql , something like this....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CreateScheduleTable 
    @TableName SYSNAME
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX); 

DECLARE @ConstraintName SYSNAME = @TableName + 'pk_Class'

SET @SQL = N' CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) 
         + N' ( ClassID INT,
                SectionNum VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
                StartTime INT,
                EndTime INT,
                Mon BIT,
                Tues BIT,
                Wed BIT,
                Thurs BIT,
                Fri BIT,
                Sat BIT,
                Sun BIT,
                TeacherID VARCHAR(6),
                RoomID INT,
                CONSTRAINT '+ QUOTENAME(@ConstraintName) 
          + N' PRIMARY KEY (ClassID, SectionNum) )'

 Exec sp_executesql @SQL

 SET @SQL = N' INSERT INTO '+ QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N'
            (ClassID, SectionNum, StartTime, EndTime, Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun, TeacherID)
             SELECT ClassID, SectionNum, StartTime, EndTime, Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun, TeacherID
            FROM SCHEDULE'

   Exec sp_executesql @SQL

END
GO
```

Comment: We decided to go the route of adding SPRING 2015 to the table. Thanks again!